# How and where should I add my SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

Good day all, am wondering if I should add my SSL certificate in my node.js server(app.js) or do I add it once I deploy it to heroku using the heroku cli? Or do I add the certificate in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying on heroku, regardless of tier, you automatically get a SSL certificate on your domain, no need to add SSL to your nodejs app.

[More info here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/app-security).

Comment: Thank you, but please does the SSL certificate given to me by heroku apply even if I change the domain name to my own choice?

Comment: Yes, the SSL certificate still applies.

Comment: @Lovelyn2001, no, rare is wrong. Heroku's automatic SSL cert only works on the default `yourapp.herokuapp.com` domain. It will not work with a custom domain. You'll need to use [ACM](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management), which requires a paid Heroku dyno, or bring your own certificate with [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl).